# Hide Adminhtnl ids selectionsColumn on customer list

Tags: magento2, grid

I can't figure out how to hide the first adminhtml column (ids) without breaking CSV export.

My **customer_listing.xml** looks like this:

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </massaction>
</listingToolbar>
<columns name="customer_columns">
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
</columns>
```

I found that when I use `<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>`column is hided correctly but CSV/XML list export breaks throwing: *'Invalid UI Component element name'*.

Is there any way to hide it without breaking export? I considered showing it and disabling by CSS, but when the column is present other columns lost the desired column order.